# How to display json data returned from PHP inside a component in Angular project

Tags: php, json, angular, interface, ngfor

I am trying to display data returned from php as JSON array into my component.

In this `ngOnInit()` I added the following script:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php').subscribe(
    (response: Response) =>{
      const data = response.json() as Partners;
      console.log(data);
      //this.keys.push(this.data);
    },
    error =>{
      console.log('error');
    }
  )
}
```

The PHP script is as the following:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once("./serverConnection.php");

class affiliatePartner
{
    public function getPartners(){
        global $conn;
        $result = array();
        $getPartners = "SELECT partner_name FROM partner";
        $execGetPartners = $conn->prepare($getPartners);
        $execGetPartners->execute();
        $result = $execGetPartners->fetchAll();

        // foreach($result as $res)
        // {
        //  $res=array('partner_name'=>$result['partner_name']);
        // }
        return json_encode($result);
    }
}
?>
```

I've got the following result:

[image]

Then, I want to display `Udemy` and `Nike` in a div:

```
  <ul *ngFor="let datas of data;">
    {{datas}}
  </ul>
```

But nothing appeared in the component.

I searched a little bit and some people used an interface, so I created an interface:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

export interface Partners{
    name: String;
}
```

In the main component:

```
import { Partners } from './Interfaces';
```

And I changed the script into:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php').subscribe(
    (response: Response) =>{
      const data = response.json() as Partners;
      console.log(data.name);
      //this.keys.push(this.data);
    },
    error =>{
      console.log('error');
    }
  )
}
```

But still no result displayed in my div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your component you need to declare a variable. You then need to store the returned result in that variable.

```
public partners: any = [];

ngOnInit(){
  this.http.get('http://aff.local/getPartners.php').subscribe(
    (response: Response) =>{
      this.partners = response.json() as Partners;
      console.log(this.partners);
    },
    error =>{
      console.log('error');
    }
  )
}
```

Once that is done, you can use the following in your html

```
<ul *ngFor="let partner of partners">
    <li>{{partner.partner_name}}>/li>
</ul>
```

To display this in a dropdown menu

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let partner of partners; let i = index">{{partner.partner_name}}</option>
</select>
```

If you're using Angular5

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let partner of partners; index as i">{{partner.partner_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It Worked. So My only error was just to put a public array variable ?

Comment: Yes, you were storing it on a variable that was scoped to within the `subscribe` event. Creating a global variable and storing it there allows you to access that variable within the html file as well. I'm glad my solution helped, please mark my answer as correct then :)

Comment: I will in 6 minutes. How can i display the array inside drop list ?

Comment: Just one more thing. I am adding let i = index but it is not working

Comment: Updated my answer again to include the index stuff

Answer (score 1):

You should create a variable at the beggining of your class

```
data: Array<Partners>;
```

Then in your subscription, instead of creating a constant for the values you get from the api, do this

```
this.data = response.json() as Partners;
```

The view should show the response now

```
<ul><li *ngFor="let datas of data">{{datas.partner_name}}</li><ul>
```